# How to make string validation via jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have some class with string fields inside it

```
    public class Variable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

My goal is to have `String name` `<= 256 characters and regexp ^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`. Can I do it somehow using Jackson annotations?

Comment: see here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated You can use "@Validate" with Spring and "@Valid" without him and any of available constraints(@Pattern for your case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

public class Variable {

    private String id;

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,256}$")
    private String name;

    public Variable() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

Comment: What about @Size(max=256). Could it work?

Comment: You can also change regex to `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$` and add `@Size`. It checks both of them and works the same way again. @Michael Kors